# How to get parts of string from text and format text by javascript

Tags: javascript

please help to resolve my question.

I have a full string:

```
var str = "I have 1000.00 USD montly to extract from 10000.00 USD. My account have 9000.00 USD."
```

What i want is:

```
var str = "I have <mark>1000.00 USD</mark> montly to extract from <mark>10000.00 USD</mark>. My account have <mark>9000.00 USD</mark>."
```

The problem is ***amount and currency*** will change every times. I want to put `<mark>` tag around amount and currency. Please guide me way to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: `The price of 12 1000 ml bottle is 500 $`. Expected output?

Comment: How do you generate the string? It would be much easier to wrap the text there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const regex = /(\d+(\.\d{1,2})? \w{1,5})/gm;
const str = `I have 1000.00 USD montly to extract from 10000.00 USD. My account have 9000.00 USD.`;
const subst = `<mark>$1</mark>`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Result: ', result);
```

Comment: `"I was born 23 years ago. So I'm 23 year old"`.

Comment: `"I was born <mark>23 years</mark> ago. So I'm <mark>23 year</mark> old"`.

Comment: indeed but instead of \w{1,5} you can define an array of strings with currencies

Comment: Yeah! That should do. Something like `/(\d+(?:\.\d+)? (?:USD|$|MAD|...))/g` will certainly narrow the results.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir You want to include **every** possible currency in the world? :P

Comment: Can run successfully @Vladu. Thanks. But if it contains 10,000 USD then, can get 10,<mark>000 USD</mark>. Is it possible to get <mark>10,000 USD</mark> also?

Comment: const regex = /((\d+\,)?\d+(\.\d{1,2})? \w{1,5})/gm; I think it will be okay.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `1000.00 USD` pattern - `digits, a dot, digits, a whitespace and the currency`.

```js
var str = "I have 1000.00 USD montly to extract from 10000.00 USD. My account have 9000.00 USD.",
    res = str.replace(/\d+\.\d+\s\w+/g, "<mark>"+ "$&" + "</mark>");
    
    console.log(res);
```

Comment: `"I weigh 15.5 killos. Meet me in 1.5 hours"`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Your example is a total science fiction ;d

Comment: Why? Because it's impossible that I weigh just 15.5 killos? :P

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir You have edited your comment, you wrote *"I was born 30.5 years ago"*. Anyways there's no way to avoid every possible scenario.

Comment: can't run and got error when i put inside my javascript code @Kind. Thx.